# A certain country has four regions: North, East, South, and West. ...

Tags: probability

A certain country has four regions: North, East, South, and West. The population of these regions are 3 million, 4 million, 5 million, and 8 million, respectively. There are 4 cities in the North, 3 in the East, 2 in the South, and there is only 1 city in the West. Each person in the country lives in exactly one of these cities.

a) What is the average size of a city in a region? (This is the arithmetic mean of the population of the cities, and is also the expected value of the population of a city chosen uniformly at random.)

b) A region of the country is chosen uniformly at random, and then a city within that region is chosen uniformly at random. What is the expected population size of this randomly chosen city?

- For part A, letting X = the size of the city, I got E(X) = 1/10[3,000,000 + 4,000,000 + 5,000,000 + 8,000,000] = 2,000,000
- For part B, 1/4[750,000 + 4/3(1,000,000) + 2,500,000 + 8,000,000] = about 3145833.33
- My answers seem off but I am not sure where exactly in my work I am off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In part $(a)$ you are asked to calculate the average size of a city in a region, so the question probably wants you to calculate average sizes for each region separately (if not, then your answer gives the correct average size of a city in the COUNTRY). Your answer to part B is correct.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri can you please expand on your explanation on part A? What would the calculations be exactly if the question wanted me to calculate average sizes for each region separately?

Comment: For calculating the average size of a city in a region, you restrict yourself to the population and number of cities in that region. For example, the average size of a city in North region is $3\text{ mil}/4=0.75\text{ mil}$. Similarly for other regions.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but do mean: E(north) = 3/4, E(east) = 4/3, E(south) = 5/2, E(west) = 8/1?